# For which values of $q$ is $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2N}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^q}{|x-y|^{N+sq}}dxdy$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Let $u=u(r)$ be radially symmetric, nonnegative and decreasing function. Let $s\in (0, 1)$ and $p, q\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $1<q<p$ and $ps<N$ with $N\in\mathbb{N}, N\ge 2$.

Assume that $u\in D^{s, p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $D^{s, p}(\mathbb{R}^N) = \left\lbrace u\in L^{Np/(N-sp)}(\mathbb{R}^N): \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2N}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{N+sp}}dxdy <+\infty\right\rbrace.$

Assume also that two positive constants $c_1, c_2>0$ exist such that for all $r\ge 1$:
$$ \frac{c_1}{r^{(N-sp)/(p-1)}}\le u(r)\le \frac{c_2}{r^{(N-sp)/(p-1)}}.$$
I would like to find suitable value of $q$ which guarantee that
$\int_{R^{2N}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^q}{|x-y|^{N+sq}}dxdy <+\infty.$

This should be a result known for people working with nonlocal problems (fractional Laplacian).Any hint or reference about the solution of this problem is well appreciated.

EDIT

1. Using the above inequality, I obtain
   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2N}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^q}{|x-y|^{N+sq}}dxdy\le 2^{q-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2N}} \left(\frac{c_1^q}{x^{(N-sp)q/(p-1)}}-\frac{c_2^q}{y^{(N-sp)q/(p-1)}}\right)\frac{1}{|x-y|^{N+sq}}dxdy.$$
2. I am adding a bounty. That result I am looking for should be something "***standard***". More information about that function $u$ and its properties are at page $11$ of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.00132.pdf).

**Thank you.**

Comment: It $u$ smooth? Without any regularity assumption on $u$ I'm not sure this is true

Comment: @JackT I edited the question.

Comment: Sorry but please could you also define $D^{s,p}(\mathbb R^N)$?

Comment: @JackT sorry, done.

Comment: The homogeneous functions like $1/|x|^a$ are not in any $L^p$ space, and so not in any Sobolev space, by Sobolev embeddings. They are in sum of $L^p$ spaces however:
$$
|x|^{-a} \in L^{d/a,\infty} \subset L^{d/a - \epsilon} + L^{d/a + \epsilon}
$$
In particular, your conditions are not possible, there is no function such that $u\in D^{s,p}$ and $u\simeq 1/|x|^a$.